# In Access 2016 VBA, is the OnChange event the best for reading a barcode?

Tags: ms-access, vba, barcode-scanner

I have an access database.  I want to bring up a form with a textbox then have a user scan a barcode into that textbox (15 to 20 characters).  Scanning the code into the textbox works great with my USB HID scanner, but once the code is scanned access just sits there.  The OnChange event seems like the correct direction.  Here is my sample code.

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()

    Debug.Print Me.Text0.Value
    Debug.Print Len(Me.Text0.Value)

End Sub
```

After I scan the barcode, this is the output.

```
00000000000000000
17
00000000000000000
17
00000000000000000
17
.
.
.
<repeated a total of 17 times>
```

Am I assuming correctly that OnCurrent is triggered for each character in the code?  Using this method I'd have to write code that would ignore all events except for one.  Which event should I capture?  Will the first change event always hold the entire code?  It just sounds like a lot of slop with a huge margin of error.

My goal is to run some code on the scanned barcode without any further user input once the code is scanned (i.e. no requirement for the user to hit enter or a button after scanning the code).  Is there something better then OnChange for this function?  Is my methodology all wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Most scanners can be programmed to add a _CrLf_ (new line) to a scanned code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, indeed, use the On Change event. My implementation would vary on how exactly your scanner works. If your scanner just enters a fixed number of lines after scanning a barcode, you could count the number of lines to see if it's finished in your On Change event, and do something if it has.

An alternative is setting the `Form.Timer` property in the On Change event to a small number, and then set the timer to 0 and do your actual work in the forms On Timer event. That way you don't have to detect the fact that the whole barcode is scanned, it will just trigger once after changing it's content, and only once (as long as the `Form.Timer` number is large enough).

Another alternative are the before and after update event, but they require the user to leave the textbox.

Comment: I ended up using your form.timer suggestion.  It worked fantastically.

Answer (score 1):

I used the onchange event and set up case statements to check for specific parts of the barcodes we scan (we have specific prefixes and lengths so it is easy to set up business rules). THe key is to using the onchnage event is allowing it to fire without taking any action until the entire scanned result is completed in the output textbox control...hence case statements to test on both on the prefix for type of barcode (e.g. a location, an asset tag, or serial ID number) and the length of the barcode (to help determine the entire scan is completed).  I setup a form with four text fields (unbound).  Fields were 'location/container', 'date/time', 'item_ID' and 'current_scan'.  The current_scan textbox had the focus so the scanner output would dump there and the VBA code in the onchange event for that control.  I used 3 or 9 code on the scanner.  My rule set checks the length of the scanned result and looks at the first three characters for the prefix and for given prefixes then checks for the length of the barcode and takes action to update the other three text boxes on the form based on the rules I established (if it is a location prefix with the correct length, then update the location textbox etc).  When the location and item are filled in, I can scan or click on the screen, commands to accept or reject the last scanned item.  If accepted, the code adds a new record to the underlying table and assigns the filled in (unbound) text box items on the form to the correct fields of the new record and saves the new record.  SO ar it works great.  My next step is to have it do a lookup against the inventory database to display information about the scanned item.  Unfortunately I don't have my code here but hope this verbage helps.